# Search parent-child relationship until parent meets a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

My table looks like this:

```
ChildPart    ParentPart    Quantity    ChildType
--------------------------------------------------
a0001        b0001         1           Bought
a0002        b0002         1           Bought
a0003        b0003         1           Bought
a0004        b0004         1           Bought
a0005        x0000         1           Made
b0001        c0001         1           Phantom
b0002        c0002         1           Phantom
b0003        x0000         1           External
b0004        c0004         1           Phantom
c0001        d0001         1           Phantom
c0002        x0000         1           External
c0004        d0004         1           Phantom
d0001        x0000         1           Made
e0004        x0000         1           External
x0000        x0000         1           Made
```

This table encloses a child-parent relationship of 4 elements. To give some extra detail, the ChildType specifies whether the part is bought, made or made by an external entity. I am interested in getting only the bought parts that are related with a parent that are done externally. However, the Phantom status should be ignored because it is a fake part made only to trace a minimal part transformation.

A better illustration of the process of every part is the following:

```
part  a0001 -> b0001 -> c0001 -> d0001 -> x0000
type  Bought - Phanto - Phanto - Made   - Final Assembly (Made)

part  a0002 -> b0002 -> x0002 -> d0000
type  Bought - Phanto - Extern - Final Assembly (Made)

part  a0003 -> b0001 -> x0000  
type  Bought - Extern - Final Assembly (Made)

part  a0004 -> b0004 -> c0004 -> d0004 -> e0004 -> x0000
type  Bought - Phanto - Phanto - Phanto - Extern - Final Assembly (Made)

part  a0005 -> x0000
type  Bought - Final Assembly (Made)
```

The final output I am interested to have is a table that relates the bought parts (a set of parts provided at the beginning) and their parents as long as they are external, and bypassing any Phantom in the middle.

If the part reaches a parent that is Made (anything else that is not External or Phantom), then it should return NULL or a flag indicating that this child does not have a Parent made externally.

I mean something like this:

```
ChildPart    ExternalParent
-----------------------------
a0001        NULL
a0002        d0004        
a0003        c0004        
a0004        b0004        
a0005        NULL
```

I been trying to use CTEs for this but without any luck yet...

This is my code. I intend to pair every child with their top External processed parent and then select the MainChild and ExternalParent columns.

```
    DECLARE @BOM TABLE(
    ChildPart VARCHAR(20)
    ParentPart VARCHAR(20)
    Quantity DEC(9,2)
    ChildType VARCHAR(20)
    )
    INSERT INTO @BOM VALUES
    ('a0001','b0001',1,'Bought')
    ,('a0002','b0002',1,'Bought')
    ,('a0003','b0003',1,'Bought')
    ,('a0004','b0004',1,'Bought')
    ,('a0005','b0005',1,'Made')
    ,('b0001','c0001',1,'Phantom')
    ,('b0002','c0002',1,'Phantom')
    ,('b0003','c0003',1,'External')
    ,('b0004','c0004',1,'Phantom')
    ,('c0001','d0001',1,'Phantom')
    ,('c0002','d0002',1,'External')
    ,('c0004','d0004',1,'Phantom')
    ,('d0001','e0001',1,'Made')
    ,('e0004','f0004',1,'External')
    ;
    DECLARE @partsToLook TABLE (ChildPart VARCHAR (20)
    INSERT INTO @partsToLook VALUES ('a0001'),('a0002'),('a0003'),('a0004'),('a0005')

    ----
    ;WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT  
            MainPart = p.ChildPart --This is to track the Main Child part we are looking the parents.
            ,ChildPart
            ,ParentPart
            ,Quantity
            ,ChildType
        FROM    @BOM b
        INNER JOIN @partsToLook p ON p.ChildPart=b.ChildPart

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  
            MainPart = tb.ChildPart
            ,ChildPart
            ,ParentPart
            ,Quantity
            ,ChildType
        FROM cte tb
        INNER JOIN @BOM b ON b.ChildPart=tb.ParentPart
    )
    SELECT MainPart,ParentPart FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected result in the question doesn't quite match the sample data. You'd better fix it to avoid confusion.

I added an explicit `StopRecursion` flag in the recursive query, which is set when recursion reaches a row that is not a `'Bought', 'Phantom', 'External'`.

Then `ROW_NUMBER` is used to pick only one row per `StartPart` and `StopRecursion` flag is used to determine whether `ExternalParent` should be set to `NULL`.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @BOM TABLE(
    ChildPart VARCHAR(20)
    ,ParentPart VARCHAR(20)
    ,Quantity DEC(9,2)
    ,ChildType VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @BOM (ChildPart,ParentPart,Quantity,ChildType) VALUES
 ('a0001','b0001',1,'Bought')
,('a0002','b0002',1,'Bought')
,('a0003','b0003',1,'Bought')
,('a0004','b0004',1,'Bought')
,('a0005','b0005',1,'Made')
,('b0001','c0001',1,'Phantom')
,('b0002','c0002',1,'Phantom')
,('b0003','c0003',1,'External')
,('b0004','c0004',1,'Phantom')
,('c0001','d0001',1,'Phantom')
,('c0002','d0002',1,'External')
,('c0004','d0004',1,'Phantom')
,('d0001','e0001',1,'Made')
,('e0004','f0004',1,'External')
;

DECLARE @partsToLook TABLE (ChildPart VARCHAR (20));
INSERT INTO @partsToLook (ChildPart) VALUES
('a0001'),
('a0002'),
('a0003'),
('a0004'),
('a0005');
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        B.ChildPart
        ,B.ParentPart
        ,B.ChildType
        ,1 AS Lvl
        ,B.ChildPart AS StartPart
        ,CASE WHEN B.ChildType NOT IN ('Bought', 'Phantom', 'External') 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS StopRecursion
    FROM
        @BOM AS B
        INNER JOIN @partsToLook AS P ON P.ChildPart = B.ChildPart

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        B.ChildPart
        ,B.ParentPart
        ,B.ChildType
        ,CTE.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
        ,CTE.StartPart
        ,CASE WHEN B.ChildType NOT IN ('Bought', 'Phantom', 'External') 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS StopRecursion
    FROM
        @BOM AS B
        INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.ParentPart = B.ChildPart
    WHERE
        CTE.StopRecursion = 0
)
,CTE_RN
AS
(
    SELECT
        StartPart
        ,ParentPart
        ,StopRecursion
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StartPart ORDER BY Lvl DESC) AS rn
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    StartPart AS ChildPart
    ,CASE WHEN StopRecursion = 1 THEN NULL ELSE ParentPart END AS ExternalParent
FROM CTE_RN
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ChildPart;
```

**Result**

```
+-----------+----------------+
| ChildPart | ExternalParent |
+-----------+----------------+
| a0001     | NULL           |
| a0002     | d0002          |
| a0003     | c0003          |
| a0004     | d0004          |
| a0005     | NULL           |
+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: I havent read your answer in detail yet but one observation is that all the parts in the bom are 'Bought', 'Phantom' or 'External'. I have updated the BOM to better explain my situation. Sorry for the confusion. I'll come back at you as soon as I read in detail your explanation. Thanks.